# outputs in tabs using markdown rather than rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, markdown

As discussed [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-tabs.html) one can produce tab-ed outputs like this using RMarkdown:

```
## Results {.tabset .tabset-pills}
```

[image]

Can something similar also be achieved with markdown? Thanks!